# Javascript onclick not working in 33 chrome, mozilla and new opera

Tags: javascript, html

I have such code and its not working in all browsers, while working on 32 version of chrome and old version of Opera. Whats wrong? How to make this code working?

```
<td align=right><a href=# onClick="demand.value=<%field0%>;submit()"><%field1%>&nbsp;</a></td>
```

Comment: That's one horrible line of code! What happened? Try `href="#"`, who knows...

Comment: And don't blame javascript alone for errors caused due to `<%field0%>`... you need to give credits to all languages involved.

Comment: consider to use a `role="button"` for the link [(MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_button_role), or use a true `<button type="button">` instead.

Comment: what is <%field0%> ? string ? int ? boolean ?

Comment: When something doesn't work in all browsers, it's usually their fault, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<td align=right><a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="demand.value=<%field0%>;submit()"><%field1%>&nbsp;</a></td>
```

Comment: It works after I push this button: <input type="submit" value="Search" name="go"></input>

Answer (score 0):

Check this.

```
<td align=right><a href="#" onClick="demand.value=<%=field0%>;submit()"><%=field1%>&nbsp;</a></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

User full path to variable:

```
 onClick="document.forms[0].fodemand.value=<%field0%>; document.forms[0].submit()"
```